# How to update Huawei P20 to Android 9

Tags: huawei, 9.0-pie, huawei-p20

I have recently bought a Huawei P20, but it cannot be updated to Android 9.

However, my old P10 has already been updated to Android 9 many months ago.

So how can the P20 be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: It was necessary to insert a SIM card. (I had tried it only with WLAN without SIM).